# Pagination and filtering issue in jquery and cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, cakephp, pagination

In the form there are filters. Based on the click of the button I make an ajax call.

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'buying', 'action'=>'purchase_orders')); ?>/'+warehouse_id+'/'+status+'/'+start_date+'/'+end_date+'/'+supplier_id, 
            function(data) {
                var table_row = '';
                $.each(data, function(key,value){ 
                    table_row += '<tr><td class="sl"><input name="checkboxlist" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'+value.PurchaseOrder.id+'"/></td><td class="name"><a href="/snow_white/buying/view_purchase_order/'+value.PurchaseOrder.id+'">'+value.PurchaseOrder.order_no+'</a></td><td class="description">'+value.PurchaseOrder.order_date+'</td><td class="description">'+value.Supplier.company_name+'</td><td class="description">'+value.Warehouse.name+'</td><td class="align-center actions"><a class="btn btn-small edit-po" href="/snow_white/buying/edit_purchase_order/'+value.PurchaseOrder.id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a><a class="btn btn-small delete-po" href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td></tr>';
                });
                $('#table-body').empty(table_row);
                $('#table-body').append(table_row);
                $('#table-division').show();
            });
```

This AJAX call will return the rows in JSON format. Using the JSON format I use the $.each in JQUERY Script and iterate to get HTML table Rows and finally append it to table body. In this situation I need pagination can any one suggest me the way to achive it.

Comment: Save yourself from pain and use a jQuery plugin like tablesorter or jqGrid. They both support ajax requests & pagination.

Answer (score -1):

Better solution for that would be to recieve the whole HTML-Results-Table as rendered HTML, not the JSON-Data and use AJAX-Pagination afterwards. 
Therefore you need to seperate the the Results-Table and the things around (the, filter and so on.) 
I usually divide it into

- a view containing Headline, Filterform, ... (`buying/purchase_orders`)
- an element, containing the resultstable (`elements/buying/purchase_orders_filter`)

My way to do that is using jQuery's AJAX - Function.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: $('base').attr('href') + 'buying/purchase_orders/warhouse_id:'+warehouse_id+'/status:'+status ...
    success: function(html){
        $('#table-division').html(html);
    }
  });
```

In your `purchase`-Function in your Controller you try to get your parameters via passedArgs (`$this->passedArgs['warehouse_id'])`,... and set up your pagination as usual.

Then you have to tell the Controller, that if the action is called via AJAX, that the element is rendered instead of the view. The `RequestHandler`is quite handy for that (added at the end of the function):

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->render('/elements/buying/purchase_orders_filter');
}
```

Also make sure, to set the Filterarguments back to the Element, you will need it for your Pagination

```
$this->set('warehouse_id',$this->passedArgs['warehouse_id']);
$this->set('status',$this->passedArgs['status']);
.
.
```

In your `purchase_orders` - View, render the Element inside the `table-division`-area (using `$this->element()`), to make sure to have an unfiltered list at startup.

To enable AJAX-pagination, add following lines:

```
<?php $paginator->options(array(
'update'=>'table-division', 
'url' => array(
    'controller'=>'buying', 
    'action'=>'purchase_orders',
    'warehouse_id' => $warehouse_id, 
    .
    .
))); ?>
```

You need to add your filter-arguments here for keeping the data filtered when the table is paginated.

a few things left:

- `$('base').attr('href')` is helpful for your AJAX request, it provides the first part of your url, so you can start off with `controller/action/...` 
   add `<base href="<?php echo $this->base; ?>" />` to your `layouts/default` in the `<head>`-Section. It's quity handy.
- make sure you have an empty `ajax.ctp` (only containing `<?php echo this->fetch('content'); ?>`) in your `layouts`- directory

Hope this helps!

Comment: Down-voting as you should never send entire HTML fragments via an AJAX web service. It gives the end user larger requests to download; increases bandwidth consumption; and is unusable in any other scenario, i.e. if I wanted to use the same endpoint in another part of my application but marked up differently—I’m stuck with your hard-coded data table mark-up.

Comment: The bandwidth point goes to you. But for the reusabilty, hardcoding it in JS as he did above is much less reuseable than rerendering elements. And cakePHP's AJAX-Pagination does the same, reloading an HTML-element, i've just added the filter-function to it. Only other solution, coming to my mind, is a JS-based-pagination, without AJAX. But tell me, if there's better practice, I'm open minded ;)

Comment: I didn’t say the original poster’s solution was better, but anything coming in via AJAX should be data only, and any templating or rendering done on the client-side. Parameters should be sent with the request to manipulate the data that comes back, and then the client-side JS deciding how to render it, whether it’s a table or list etc.